# Bot creation failed with error: Not Found

Tags: continuous-integration, osx-server, xcode-bots

[image]

I restored a server, running OSX Server, from backup and now just get the above error when trying to add a new bot through Xcode.

Is there any log file in which I can get more information?

Has anyone seen this before?

The system.log has some messages from xcscontrol.

```
Mar 25 13:13:04 onato.local xcscontrol[4164]: Xcode version: 6.2 (6C131e) (OS X SDK 13F26, iOS SDK 12D508)
Mar 25 13:13:04 onato.local xcscontrol[4164]: Server version: 4.0.3 (14S350)
Mar 25 13:13:04 onato.local xcscontrol[4164]: OS X version: 10.10.2 (14C1514)
Mar 25 13:13:04 onato.local nsurlstoraged[205]: realpath() returned NULL for /var/root/Library/Caches/xcscontrol
Mar 25 13:13:04 onato.local nsurlstoraged[205]: The read-connection to the DB=/var/root/Library/Caches/xcscontrol/Cache.db is NOT valid.  Unable to determine schema version.
Mar 25 13:13:04 onato.local nsurlstoraged[205]: realpath() returned NULL for /var/root/Library/Caches/xcscontrol
Mar 25 13:13:04 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Mar 25 13:13:04 onato.local nsurlstoraged[205]: ERROR: unable to determine file-system usage for FS-backed cache at /var/root/Library/Caches/xcscontrol/fsCachedData. Errno=13
Mar 25 13:13:04 onato.local thermald[28]: invalid attribute or value, default to yes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up resetting xcscontrol and setting up Xcode again.

`sudo xcrun xcscontrol --reset`

The relevant log files are in `/Library/Developer/XcodeServer/Logs`

Answer (score 0):

When I get that error, I have to remove the server from Xcode and then re-add it

Comment: Thanks, but I had already tried that. The problems was on the server not the client.